# Div not appearing - css issue

Tags: html, css

I have the following code where the bottom section is not displaying and I am not sure why.

This is the part that doesn't display:

```
<div class="tribeconversation">
        <div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: hey everyone</div>
        <div class="tribeconvo">JakeP97: hello joey</div>
        <div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: oi m8, whats up</div>
        <div class="tribeconvo">TheKid: LOL hey JakeP</div>
        <div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: RIP</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/smvbaa6u/

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with items being `display: inline-block`

Comment: Um, `font-size: 0;` maybe?

Comment: LMAO too much coding fried my brain. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `font-size: 0` to `tribeactivity` - reset it to `initial` for the `tribeconversation` - see demo below:

```css
#tribeactivity {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0;
} 
 
#Amuraheader {
 font-family: 'survival';
 font-size: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #2B32E4;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ffffff;
}
 
#Malosiheader {
 font-family: 'survival';
 font-size: 80px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #DB282B;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px #ffffff;
 margin-top: 30px;
} 

.tribeavi {
 width: 149px;
 height: 186px;
 background-size: cover;
 display: inline-block;
} 

.tribeaviname {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'survival';
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 27px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 top: 156px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color: white;
} 

.tribeconversation {
 display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="tribeactivity">
     <div id="Amuraheader">Amura</div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/Riku1274-14154.png?v=2053856125')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Riku1274</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/realityobsessed-7881.png?v=625345208')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Reality</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://www.zwooper.com/media/avatars/johnnyscott1127-7443.png?v=590056866')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Johnny</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/exploremedora-7274.png?v=1507280925')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">ExploreMe</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/yswimmer96-1356.png?v=386446076')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Yswimmer</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/xStqqd-16258.png?v=173536863')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">xStqqd</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/AngelOfWater-885.png?v=430260016')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Angelofwater</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/a07strand-9696.png?v=259628760')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">A07Strand</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/JakeP97-3100.png?v=529092857')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">JakeP97</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/joeyc-13212.png?v=101411917')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">JoeyC</div>
     </div>
          
     
     
     <div id="Malosiheader">Malosi</div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/SuperDoodle-2870.png?v=1868660820')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">SuperDoodle</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/wwxcrunner1-1056.png?v=48014610')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">wwxcrunner</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/King_Canine-10700.png?v=327204573')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">King_Canine</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/WILLZ14-8313.png?v=620214729')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Willz14</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/BostonRob524-7935.png?v=1279836291')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">BostonRob</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/devon19-10680.png?v=168166820')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Devon19</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/Alvarovidalpuga-8630.png?v=1796517703')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Alvaro</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/Ginger7-4349.png?v=564697580')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Ginger7</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/TheKid-22456.png?v=626667976')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">TheKid</div>
     </div>
     <div class="tribeavi" style="background-image: url('http://zwooper.com/media/avatars/joeyc-13212.png?v=101411917')">
      <div class="tribeaviname">Krystiian</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="tribeconversation">
   <div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: hey everyone</div>
   <div class="tribeconvo">JakeP97: hello joey</div>
   <div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: oi m8, whats up</div>
   <div class="tribeconvo">TheKid: LOL hey JakeP</div>
   <div class="tribeconvo">Joeyc: RIP</div>
  </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The div `.tribeconvo` inherits a `font-size:0;` from `#tribeactivity`.

```
#tribeactivity {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Therefore, the `.tribeconversation` div has a `height:0` and doesn't appear. Just add a font size bigger than 0 to `.tribeconvo` to fix this.

```
.tribeconvo{
    font-size: 16px;
}
```